# Why does my Image disappear when navigation bar is resized

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar which is responsive and has a dropdown menu. When I resize my browser so that the break point is reach and the navigation goes to its mobile view the below hero image will disappear and heading tags are partially seen, I'm not sure and can't see what is causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML

```
    <section class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="#!">image</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">header 10</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">header 9</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">header 8</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">header 7</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">header 6</a>
            </li>
                        <li>
              <a href="#!">header 5</a>
            </li>
                        <li>
              <a href="#!">header 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">header3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">header 2</a>
        </li>
                <li>
          <a href="#!">Header 1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Bring Your Garden And Driveway to life </h1>
    <h2>Scroll Down To Learn More</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    @charset "UTF-8";
.navigation {
  height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
}

.brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  color: grey;
}
nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}
nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

/* Mobile navigation */
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }

  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }

  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}
#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: url(https://stmed.net/sites/default/files/leaves-wallpapers-25246-1391025.jpg);
  height: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/*==========WELCOME-TEXT==========*/
.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.hero-text h2 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 22px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .hero-text h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Slabo 20px', serif;
  }

  .hero-text h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

Below is a jsfiddle of my code 
https://jsfiddle.net/wkqph6x4/1/

Comment: You can add a clear fix to the hero-image. add clear:both to the .hero-image. I would also suggest to try to avoid using floats. I see you are using flex which in my opinion is far more powerful and you will be less prone to errors that appear with floats. Do a quick search for a flexbox cheat sheet and try to recreate the navigation without using floats.

Comment: Although you accepted the answer to add a width to the container, it's actually your `nav` element set to `float: right` that's causing the issue.

Comment: I added an answer that addresses the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct working answer - even if setting the width on the flex item solved a portion of the issue. I moved the `nav { float: right }` to the media query above 799px and then added some styles (z-index and position) for below to the `nav` element.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wkqph6x4/24/

```js
(function($) { // Begin jQuery
  $(function() { // DOM ready
    // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      // Close one dropdown when selecting another
      $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    // Hamburger to X toggle
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); // end DOM ready
})(jQuery); // end jQuery
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.navigation {
  height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
}

.brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  color: grey;
}
nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}
nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

/* Mobile navigation */
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }

  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }

  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  
  nav {
    float: right;
    
  }
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}
#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: url(https://stmed.net/sites/default/files/leaves-wallpapers-25246-1391025.jpg);
  height: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/*==========WELCOME-TEXT==========*/
.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.hero-text h2 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 22px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .hero-text h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Slabo 20px', serif;
  }

  .hero-text h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="#!">image</a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">header 10</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">header 9</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">header 8</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">header 7</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#!">header 6</a>
            </li>
                        <li>
              <a href="#!">header 5</a>
            </li>
                        <li>
              <a href="#!">header 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">header3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">header 2</a>
        </li>
                <li>
          <a href="#!">Header 1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Bring Your Garden And Driveway to life </h1>
    <h2>Scroll Down To Learn More</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give `width: 100%` to `.hero-image` class.

I think your image's width is bigger than 783px. Hence, whenever div width goes below 783px, your image stops showing and width of .hero-image goes to 0px.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a width on the `.hero-image` class. In this case `width: '100%';` should suffice, although, it can be whatever you'd like it to be.

You'll notice once you do this there will be a `15px` gap between the navigation and the hero image, which is from bottom padding on the `nav` element. If that's a stylistic / design choice then no need to worry about removing or adjusting that. Just wanted to give a heads up.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wxbj0L17/1/

Answer (score 1):

Once you trigger the mobile menu below 798px in the media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
```

The two block cause it to disappear.

nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }